# EF Code-First doesn't update Sets immediately

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 website with Entity Framework Code-First. What's happening is that in the Index action, I get some TransactionJournal objects from the database, call a method called CreateTransactions(), that, basically, create some transactions and add them to the ICollection in the TransactionJournal. Then, I save the context, and then query for all Transactions, and then they are not there! But if I just refresh the page, I will get the transactions generated at the first time, that didn't appear, but not the ones from this time. There's a lot of code, so, I'll try to mock the parts that are important here so that you can see.

A piece of the TransactionJournal:

```
public class TransactionJournal {
    public long TransactionJournalID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

A piece of the Index action:

```
IDbSet<TransactionJournal> journal_dbset = Context.Set<TransactionJournal>();
ICollection<TransactionJournal> journals = journal_dbset.Where( ... ).ToList();

foreach(TransactionJournal j in journals)
    j.CreateTransactions(); // Create some transactions and add it to the Transactions collection

Context.Commit(); // This actually calls the SaveChanges() method, only

IDbSet<Transaction> trans_dbset = Context.Set<Transaction>();
ICollection<Transaction> trans = trans_dbset.Where( ... ).ToList(); // The transactions just created are NOT here! But those created in previews Index action calls are!
```

It's like if the SaveChanges() don't immediately updates the Sets in the Context object. What should I do to get these just created transactions?

Comment: Is the CreateTransactions create the TransactionScope() object or it is just your domain related stuff?

Comment: did you use the transaction control in the data persistence logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CreateTransactions did you make a call to flag the object in the context to be updated?

```
context.Entry(j).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: I was not doing it. But it didn't work neither. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you able to post the code for the Transaction class?  Does the Transaction have a navigation property to the TransactionJournal?

Comment: Dude, that was a model bug in the Transaction class. I'm really sorry. I'll accept your answer, your comment made me see where I was screwing it up.

Comment: @Alaor - To make this question and answer more helpful it would be great for you to elaborate on what you were screwing up.